# Preventing one domain from redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following setup in my .htaccess file which diverts everything except the /dlg and /members folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dlg(/?$|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members(/?$|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*mysite.co.uk.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to create a new Wordpress site on newsite.co.uk  but it keeps diverting to mysite.co.uk

What would I need to add to prevent newsite.co.uk from diverting whilst keeping everything else the same?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not doing this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do not redirect if URI starts with /dlg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?dlg(/.*)?$ [NC]
# Do not redirect if URI starts with /members
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?members(/.*)?$ [NC]
# Do not redirect if domain is *.mysite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*\.mysite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
# Do not redirect if domain is *.newsite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*\.newsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Explanation is in the comments*

#### Note:

Delete you Browser cache before testing any kind of redirecting. Browser tend to remember 301  redirecting, and do not go to the server any more.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code.  Still not working though.

If I type newsite.co.uk it redirects to www.mysite.co.uk and if I type www.newsite.co.uk it stays on www.newsite.co.uk but displays the old site not my new Wordpress page?